# Как инвертировать оси в Unity

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть точка спавна игрока в моей мультиплеерной игре, но беда в том, что для того, чтобы игрок смотрел лицом к другому игроку нужно повернуть модель в другую сторону. Для этого я просто развернул точку спавна, но из-за этого на этом игроке, который оказался в точке спавна2, управление инвертировалось, т.е. при нажатии влево он шел вправо и наоборот, также вместо вперед шел назад и наоборот. Для того, чтобы решить данную проблему, я думаю, что нужно каким-то образом инвертировать оси x и z(скрин прилагается), но я не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста, может можно это сделать каким-нибудь коротким скриптом, который можно повесить на спавнпоинт2.[image: Скрин осей]

P.S. просто повернуть не вариант, т.к. тогда игрок будет смотреть в другую сторону

Comment: Ну точку спавна-то ты смог повернуть, а в чем проблема сделать то же самое с моделью? Можно сделать это и в коде, вроде бы это `transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0)`, если мне память не изменяет. Естественно transform берем объекта с моделью.

Comment: > *управление инвертировалось, т.е. при нажатии влево он шел вправо и наоборот, также вместо вперед шел назад и наоборот.* Догадываюсь, что вы неправильно в коде задали вектора направления движения. Покажите, как вы реализовали движение.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, код управления правильный. Он работает хорошо. У меня мультиплеер, код инвертировался для второго игрока, который подключается на сервер из-за того, что я повернул точку спавна